# Random item from listbox every 0,8 second

Tags: vb.net, random, listbox

i have a code that you see below. Can you tell me how to optimize that? Because sometimes when I click random picker (this code shows random items every 0.8 sec, like 'roll the wheel') it isn't showing f.e. 20 items, like I defined... I just want to make this script work by that: I click a button and it is rolling the positions from a listbox, and showing items that aren't

```
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim rndIndex As Integer = rnd.Next(10, 20)

For ill As Integer = 0 To rndIndex
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim randomIndex As Integer = rnd.Next(0, lCount)
    If Not Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items(randomIndex) Then
        Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items(randomIndex)
        Delay(0.08)
    Else
        rndIndex = rndIndex + 1
    End If
Next
```

That doesn't work, because sometimes I see only 6-8 different items. It could be like that: I've got 10 numbers (0-9), and it puts the following numbers into label every 0,8 secs: *1, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1, 5, 8, 6, 3, 0, 3, 1, 5*.

Comment: Why `rndIndex = rndIndex + 1` in a loop? Also, your `If` block does nothing practical. You only delay if in the if statement, which means you are biasing your randomness. Step through your logic carefully, and you should be able to fix it.

Comment: its working but sometimes not showing 20 times, only 5..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I should do this but there's so many things wrong with your code that it will be rather arduous to be bring it up to scratch by steps.  Basically, here's how I would display a random item from a `ListBox` in a `Label` every 0.8 seconds without ever repeating the same item twice in a row:

```
Private ReadOnly rng As New Random

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'This is done in code here for clarity but you'd normally do this in the designer.
    Timer1.Interval = 800
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Get all the items from the ListBox.
    Dim items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList()

    'Remove the currently displayed item.
    items.Remove(Label1.Text)

    'Get a random item from the remainder and display it.
    Label1.Text = items(rng.Next(items.Count))
End Sub
```

As I said in my comment, no loop. The `Timer` component is specifically intended to be used when you want to perform an action regularly.  Notice also that the currently-displayed item is taken out of the equation before the random number is even generated, so there's never a problem with repeats.

EDIT:

Here is modified code based on what I think I missed the first time:

```
Private ReadOnly rng As New Random
Private tickCount As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'This is done in code here for clarity but you'd normally do this in the designer.
    Timer1.Interval = 800
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    tickCount = rng.Next(10, 20)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    tickCount -= 1

    If tickCount = 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If

    'Get all the items from the ListBox.
    Dim items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList()

    'Remove the currently displayed item.
    items.Remove(Label1.Text)

    'Get a random item from the remainder and display it.
    Label1.Text = items(rng.Next(items.Count))
End Sub
```

I also made a slight modification to the original code because the last line was getting the item at a random index from `ListBox1.Items` instead of `items`.

Comment: doesnt work.. it is randomizing items all the time, not fixed times, like:

Comment: Dim rndIndex As Integer = rnd.Next(10, 20) did

Comment: You're explain yourself very poorly but I think I understand.  Are you saying that you first want to generate a random number ion the range 10 to 20, and then you want to display a random item from your `ListBox` every 0.8 seconds that many times?  If so, that's an easy modification.  I'll update the answer to reflect that.  If that's not want you want, please try again to explain CLEARLY.